# what is the best way to handle endpoint which will be either long running or repeating?

Tags: node.js, optimization, endpoint

I am working on a project where let's say the test case is we have a lot of third party apis in one particular end point to make payments and we have to wait for every one of that endpoint so that we can use it in the next one. so currently I was just using a sync await for this but it's taking too long and it's way too confusing. example

```
PaymentHandler(){
 constructor(){ // we aill declare all the data and its initial value}

 async function1(){//it will call a certain api and store that data in class}

 async function2(){//it will call a certain api and store that data in class}

 async function3(){//it will call a certain api and store that data in class}

 async function4(){//it will call a certain api and store that data in class}
}
```

and i am calling this class in node where i am using it as but in her their is a await which is necessary because after calling function 2 we'll have to wait around 2nd to get an updated data from function three If we don't wait after function 2 we get payment status as unclaimed but if we just wait for two second  the transaction is being processed by the third party API in that time and we get the transaction status as successful. This is because the the payment can contain at most 10k transaction at a time.

```
 const obj = new PaymentHandler()
    await obj.function1(res);
    await obj.function2(res,payment_details);
    await sleep(2000);
    await obj.function3(res);
    await obj.function4(res);
```

I am doing this kind of think first time and not sure is it a good approach this, any suggestion that might help me in this using this approach I am getting my response in around 9 seconds which is a long waiting time for client.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways you can handle these. But I recommend use the worker process `worker_threads` with cron jobs. Worker threads can help the performance greatly and it was made for this kind of task bc it can prevent them from causing problems for other parts bc it's isolated.

Also, it heavily depends on the specific requirements of your application and the types of tasks you need to handle.

[docs](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html). Plus there are many libraries which makes it easier to work with.
cheers